Set cookie on localhost from production endpoint
Is there any way to set a cookie for localhost from an API running on a domain?
For example:

Load localhost at http://localhost:5173
Request https://example.com/login endpoint
Login endpoint can tell the request came from localhost and returns an extra Set-Cookie header that works specifically for localhost
Both cookies are set correctly, one with Domain=example.com the other with Domain=localhost

I've already tried explicitly setting Domain=localhost but as explained in this question that's not possible: Cookies on localhost with explicit domain
We're working with microservices and I'd like to be able to mix production APIs with APIs I'm currently developing without starting all of them locally.
